# Eclipse running and compiling error

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, compiler-errors, eclipse-3.5

I have copied eclipse Galileo from a common sharing folder at work,they normally run with Java 6,I want to work with java 7 to do selenium tests,I have added java 7 jres in java build path,but It still compiles with Java6 so it gives me error as below :

> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError

.When I change path from jdk6 to jdk7 in eclipse.ini eclipse doesn't launch,and I can't check the "use compliance from execution environment on the java build path" in java compiler settings,I can't install another version of eclipse because of company policy.

Comment: why are you using so old libraries. it's Java 1.8 available now.

Comment: when I use java 1.8 it gives me another error on code,the solution to it was to use 7,if I use it won't I have the same problem that i have with 7?

Comment: you are using which operating system

Comment: I use Windows 7, 64

Comment: In location C:\Program Files\Java how many version of java present?

Comment: in program files 2:1.7 and 1.8,but the path I have in eclipse.ini is D:\Applications\Java\jdk1.6.0_13\bin\javaw.exe and when I change it to the jdk i have in  C:\Program Files\Java Eclipse doesn't launch

Comment: I'd suggest uninstalling all versions of java, then just reinstalling **one**.

Comment: Aha.. you need to check your envrionment variable .. surely you have given the path of old java 1.6

Comment: refer below link :- https://javatutorial.net/set-java-home-windows-10

Comment: It's having detail of win 10 but it is kinda similar

Comment: Remove the 1.6 from path variable and just give the path of 1.8

Comment: No my environment variable is set to jdk7

Comment: open cmd and type java -version .. what version you can see

Comment: 1.7 the same one I had set in environment variable

Comment: Then you should try to download new eclipse and run new jars and see if it works if it works then you have to change your JRE SYSTEM Library in your envrinment

Comment: Exactly I can't download new eclipse ... software downloads r blocked :(